# Why python division remainder operator just works for integer denominator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

While working with the division remainder operator **%** in python 2.7 I faced an unexpected behavior (at least for me) when using it with decimal denominators. Bellow an example:

```
>>> 0.1%0.1
0.0                 # as expected
>>> 0.2%0.1
0.0                 # as expected
>>> 0.3%0.1
0.09999999999999998 # what the hell?
>>> 0.4%0.1
0.0                 # aw expected
>>> 0.5%0.1
0.09999999999999998 # what the hell?
```

Why the operations **0.3%0.1** and **0.5%0.1** return the result above instead of **0.0** as in the other cases and as I was expecting?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like floating point numbers being inaccurate, see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

It's how [floats behave](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) :

```
>>> '%.30f' % 0.2
'0.200000000000000011102230246252'
>>> '%.30f' % 0.3
'0.299999999999999988897769753748'
```

If you want exact results, you could multiply every number by 10 and work with integers.